# Read existing notifications on Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

How can I read existing notifications on Android? I want to be able to grab all the pending/existing notifications, parse them, and try to grab any information them. For instance, if my device had notifications from an SMS app, then I want to be able to read whatever information I could (if possible) from the notification. Is this possible?

Note that I am NOT asking for an active notification listener/receiver. I just want to be able to parse existing notifications on-demand.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On devices with Android 4.3 and newer (API level 18) it is possible to use the [NotificationListenerService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) and its function `getActiveNotifications()` to get a list of all outstanding notifications visible to the user. You can also react on each new notification by using `onNotificationPosted`.

On older devices, the only way to get access to the android notifications is to implement an [AccessibilityService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html) to react on incoming `TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED`-events.

Comment: Thanks. For older (< API 18) devices, is it possible to get active notifications any time, instead of "reacting" to incoming notifications?